# how to use SQLITE in qt webassembly

Tags: qt, webassembly, emscripten

I want to use sqlite in my application. I compile sqlite in desktop and it compile successfully but when I compile it with qt web-assembly I get ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: sql with emsdk 1.38.27-64bit.So I use emsdk 1.38.30-64bit with thread feature but I could not compile a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

QtSql is not supported by Qt webassembly. See [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_WebAssembly#Known_issues_and_platform_notes).

Comment: How can I have a database in my application? I need sqlite in my application.